# How do I insert a document on a time series mongodb collection that isn’t created yet?

Tags: database, mongodb, insert

I want to insert documents into a time series collection (which will only be created when inserting a document for the first time). It's possible?
Using something like db.insertOne(upsert, params) where 'params' indicates that it is a time series collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of creating a time-series collection **yet** using the `insert` command if it doesn't exist.

You have to perform an if condition which checks if the collection exists beforehand and perform the insert operation.

You can make use of the `findOne` trick where you project only the `_id` key and check if a document is returned, although it will try to run the create database command even if it exists but have 0 documents in it, its way better than the `List-Collection` command and looping through the collections in your DB.

```
var foundDoc = db.collection.findOne({}, {"_id": 1});
if (foundDoc == null) {
  db.createCollection(
    "collection",
    {
       "timeseries": {
          "timeField": "timestamp",
       },
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what parameters do you use in the insert command to specify that the collection is a time series and not a normal one?

Comment: Sorry @GabrielCard, I forgot to read the title while writing the answer. I was careless. I have updated the answer. Hope it helps and is what you are looking for. Sorry again, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't mention a specific programming language so I'll throw my golang answer into the mix. This code will check if a timeseries collection exists and create it if it doesn't. You can safely run this code on startup in golang `init()` or `main()` functions as necessary. I use uppercase local variables here as they're actually global and exported throughout my app (API).

```
    var err error
    Client, err = mongo.NewClient(options.Client().ApplyURI(ConnectionString))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = Client.Connect(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    Database = Client.Database(Name)

    var timeseriesMetricsName = "timeseries_metrics"
    exists := false
    names, err := Database.ListCollectionNames(ctx, bson.D{}, nil)
    for _, name := range names {
        if name == timeseriesMetricsName {
            exists = true
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        // Timeseries collections must be explicitly created so we explicitly create it here
        err = Database.CreateCollection(ctx, timeseriesMetricsName, &options.CreateCollectionOptions{
            TimeSeriesOptions: &options.TimeSeriesOptions{
                TimeField:   "created",
                MetaField:   aws.String("metadata"),
                Granularity: aws.String("hours"),
            }})
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(fmt.Sprintf("Error creating collection [%s]: [%+v]", timeseriesMetricsName, err))
        } else {
            fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Successfully created %s table for the first time.", timeseriesMetricsName))
        }
    }

    // Initialize normal collections or 'tables'
    AdminColl = Database.Collection("admins")
```